# How to return if a field exists or not in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm programming a site of real estate, and have 2 tables: Imovel and images in the table images I have a field that says if it is photo main or is a normal photo.
as I do to see what that might not have main photo.
because when I give select tables relating it returns me more normal photos do not tell me if that is Imovel main photo.
I used these queries:

this returned me the main photos:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel 
INNER JOIN imagens ON imagens.imovel_id = imovel.id_imovel 
WHERE imagens.tipo = "capa"
```

this returned me the normal photos:

```
SELECT * FROM imovel 
INNER JOIN imagens ON imagens.imovel_id = imovel.id_imovel 
WHERE imagens.tipo = "outros"
```

most did not to do what I want, which is to see if you have main photo related to imovel

Comment: Your English is poor, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do and what's wrong with the queries you have. The first query returns the main photos, why doesn't that tell you if you have a main photo related to each `imovel`?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yes it is poor because I do not speak in English, what I want is to see what that might have no main photo.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `LEFT JOIN`. I'm not 100% sure I understand your exact question, but I think this is the query you need.

```
SELECT imovel.*
FROM imovel 
LEFT JOIN imagens ON imagens.imovel_id = imovel.id_imovel AND imagens.tipo = "capa"
WHERE imagens.imovel_id IS NULL
;
```

The results for this will consist of all `imovel` records that did not have an associated `imagens` with a `tipo = "capa"`

---

Optionally, if you instead `SELECT *` and omit the `WHERE imagens.imovel_id IS NULL`, you will receive all `imovel` records and the data for the associated "capa" imagens ones (or null if there are none for the JOINed imovel one.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, what I meant is that I need to return the Imovel that has no main photo.

Comment: worked thank you, descupe by my English is not my native language